# Windows 10 - bring background task into foreground

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler, background

I have a scheduled task that runs an exe in the background. Every once in a while I'm suspicious that the exe isn't running properly but I have no way to see the output since it's hidden and I can only be aware of the process in task manager.

**Question**

Is it possible to bring a background task to the foreground?

Comment: You should be able to see such a task minimized or hidden in the Task Bar.  Look there - it should be underlined. That is what I do and how I find things I expect but do not see in the foreground.

Comment: Maybe you can find it in notification area's more icons area?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Task Scheduler tasks by default cannot interface with the logged-in user
session/desktop.

The isolation rules of scheduled tasks change with each new Windows version,
but do define the task with "Run only when user is logged on".
When this option is selected, your user account should be displayed under
"When running the task, use the following user account:".

With these options, the scheduled task will be able to interface with the
desktop session of the defined user, so it can be brought to the front.

You may undo the above once you no longer wish to see the task's window.

Comment: This, however, does not change the currently running task. You need to set this option in TaskScheduler before starting your task.

Answer (score 0):

In the light of the answer by @harrymc I'm not sure I've understood the question but I'll plough on anyway.

If you have a lot of tasks open (including Task Manager) you can use Alt/Tab to see a list of everything that's running and bring a selected one to the top.

1. Press and hold **Alt**

then, whilst still holding

2a. Repeatedly tap and release **Tab** to cycle through the windows. When you're on the one you want, release Tab and it will come to the top.

or (better)

2b. While hold **Alt**, tap **Tab** once and then mouse-click on the one you're interested in. It will come to the front.

or

2c. Examine the thumbnail you are interested in - it will show you the current state of what's running.

---

You can also experiment with **WindowKey** [image: (flag key)] plus **Tab**.

There are other shortcuts depending on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Tasks run by the Task Scheduler do not show when you do  Alt-Tab.

Comment: @Martin Argerami - Thanks, I obviously misunderstood. I'll delete this answer soon.

Comment: In particular, Tasks run by TaskScheduler with the `Run whether user is logged in or not` option set: do not have a window, so do not show up in the Alt-Tab list of windows.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica 2 years and still not deleted!

Comment: @chasly, I'm glad you haven't deleted this answer, because this is exactly what *doesn't* work in my case, and it's driving me nuts.  Occasionally I see a window I can't identify when tabbing through windows, and I am unable to bring to foreground with the procedure you describe above.  Consequently, I cannot use Process Explorer to identify the process which owns the window. How can I find out which process this mysterious window belongs to?